# What is the cause of 'Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths FAILED' during react-native build?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

**> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths FAILED**
17 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 14 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform react-native-reanimated-71-jsc.aar (project :react-native-reanimated) to match attributes {artifactType=android-res}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: D:\Codes\ReactNative\Ritu\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\react-native-reanimated-71-jsc.aar.
> > Transform's input file does not exist: D:\Codes\ReactNative\Ritu\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\react-native-reanimated-71-jsc.aar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)

**error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081**

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

I'm trying build the app when i run the app error get shows!!